# Unity Custom Editor NullReferenceException When SerializedProperty Has Any Accessor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accessor, unity-editor

I am trying to make a custom editor in Unity for a ScriptableObject class which has private fields like such:

[image: ScriptableObject class]

But has soon as one of my fields has an accessor (I also tried properties with get;), I get the following error when I try to see my ScriptableObject in the inspector.

[image: NullReferenceException]

I made some tests and it works perfectly without accessors. For instance, I can see the field "test".
Here is the code for my custom editor:

[image: Custom editor script]

Any idea? I would not believe a custom editor for a class that has accessors would not be supported.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Unity (C#), why am I getting a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413907/in-unity-c-why-am-i-getting-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please [**don't post images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with an "accessor". And note that [properties are **not** serialized by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) at all.

---

The mistake is pretty simple: Your field's name is **not** `ingredients` but rather `_ingredients`!

Therefore `FindProperty("ingredients")` returns `null` since it doesn't find any field called `ingredients`.

(This is assuming of course that `Item` is a `[Serializable]` type at all.)

---

To avoid exactly this type of issues I usually prefer to embed the editor into the type itself and use e.g.

```
public class YourType : MonoBehaviour /*or ScriptableObject*/
{
    [SerializeField] private int _someField;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(YourType))]
    private class YourTypeEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty _someFieldProperty;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _someFieldProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_someField));
        }

        ...
    }
#endif
}
```

so whenever you rename the fields it will be fixed in the Inspector automatically

Comment: Also. From the first part. No list is made so the list can be null

Comment: @BugFinder the list is a `[SerializeField]` so Unity's serializer will automatically initialize it .. assuming of course that `Item` is actually a serializable type ;)

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I can't believe I made such mistake... Also sorry for putting images of my codes, I'll do that more properly next time.

Comment: This fixed my issue... I had renamed the field inside the class for a property drawer.