# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. By Unity tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I follow a Unity Tutorial to program a version of flappy bird but I get the error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Parallaxer.Shift () (at Assets/scripts/Parallaxer.cs:130)
Parallaxer.Update () (at Assets/scripts/Parallaxer.cs:75)
uijk,hfgmjdcfmhfc,ghvkmbgµfhj,ddgxngsdfaf

```
This is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallaxer : MonoBehaviour
{
   class PoolObject
    {
        public Transform transform;
        public bool inUse;
        public PoolObject(Transform t) { transform = t; }
        public void Use() { inUse = true; }
        public void Dispose() { inUse = false; }

    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct YSpawnRange
    {
        public float min;
        public float max;
    }
   

    public GameObject Prefab;
    public int poolSize;
    public float shiftSpeed;
    public float spawnRate;

    public YSpawnRange ySpawnRange;
    public Vector3 defaultSpawnPos;
    public bool spawnImmediate;
    public Vector3 immediateSpawnPos;
    public Vector2 targetAspectRatio;

    float spawnTimer;
    float targetASpect;
    PoolObject[] poolObjects;
    GameManager game;

    private void Awake()
    {
        
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        game = GameManager.Instance;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        GameManager.OnGameOverConfirmed += OnGameOverConfirmed;
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        GameManager.OnGameOverConfirmed -= OnGameOverConfirmed;
    }

    void OnGameOverConfirmed()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            poolObjects[i].Dispose();
            poolObjects[i].transform.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
        }
        if (spawnImmediate)
        {
            SpawnImmediate();
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (game.GameOver) return;

        Shift();
        spawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTimer > spawnRate)
        {
            Spawn();
            spawnTimer = 0;
        }
    }
    
        
    

    void Configure()
    {
        targetASpect = targetAspectRatio.x / targetAspectRatio.y;
        poolObjects = new PoolObject[poolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
            Transform t = go.transform;
            t.SetParent(transform);
            t.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
            poolObjects[i] = new PoolObject(t);
        }

        if (spawnImmediate)
        {
            SpawnImmediate();
        }

    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        if (t == null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.x = defaultSpawnPos.x;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.min, ySpawnRange.max);
        t.position = pos;
    }

    void SpawnImmediate()
    {
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        if (t == null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.x = immediateSpawnPos.x;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.min, ySpawnRange.max);
        t.position = pos;
        Spawn();
    }

    void Shift()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            poolObjects[i].transform.position += -Vector3.right * shiftSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            CheckDisposeObject(poolObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    void CheckDisposeObject(PoolObject poolObject)
    {
        if (poolObject.transform.position.x < -defaultSpawnPos.x)
        {
            poolObject.Dispose();
            poolObject.transform.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
        }
    }

    Transform GetPoolObject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!poolObjects[i].inUse)
            {
                poolObjects[i].Use();
                return poolObjects[i].transform;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Unity (C#), why am I getting a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413907/in-unity-c-why-am-i-getting-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `Configure` in `Start` or `Awake`. Otherwise the `poolObjects` array doesn't get initialized and trying to access `poolObjects[i]` in `Shift` will cause the NullRefrence error.