# Not able to change text from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

**How it should work** - when i click on the UI button, the score increases and is displayed using text.

**How it's working** - An error that says '*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*'

There are two scripts on two different game objects.

**Player Script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    ScoreManager scoreManager;
    private void Start()
    {
        scoreManager = new ScoreManager();
    }

    public void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreManager.IncrementScore();
    }
}
```

**ScoreManager Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score = 0;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;

    public void IncrementScore()
    {
        score++;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I use Debug.Log(score.ToString()), it displays the score in the console. But when I use textmeshprougui, it gives an error.

Also, I've dragged the text into the inspector, so that cannot be a problem for the null referrance. I've checked it multiple times.

Why am I not able to update the text from another script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Unity (C#), why am I getting a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413907/in-unity-c-why-am-i-getting-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null reference exception is in your **Player.cs** script and caused because of the code in your `Start()` method

```cs
ScoreManager scoreManager;

private void Start()
{
    scoreManager = new ScoreManager();
}
```

Remove the code in your `Start()` method. Because there is a field `ScoreManager scoreManager;`, you drag the gameobject which has the script **ScoreManager.cs** into its slot in the **Player.cs** script. Now you have the reference of the ScoreManager.cs script in your **Player.cs** script.

Now, you are resetting its reference in your `Start()` method. This caused the null reference exception.